# How delete height row for table?

Tags: wordpress, html-table

I have problem with tables in Wordpress. When I create table in my post, Wordpress automatically add height for td/tr element. In result I have a lot of space in row. I have many tables in my site... have you any idea how delete parameter height in `style=""` for this elements and set height auto for this?

Comment: May I ask what you are using these tables for?

Comment: I use this table to present timetable events. J create this table using Advanced TinyMce.

Comment: Have you tried to apply some CSS to the table rows/cells? I always try to avoid HTML tables btw, even when I have to display data in a table structure.